# GoogleAnalytics - swift error

Tags: xcode, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods, unwrap

I am using cocoa-pod for Google Analytics.

**Pod file**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'MyProject' do
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
end
```

**Bridging header**

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

Everything's work fine but after adding GoogleAnalytics into my pod Xcode detect some error which should not be.

```
func design(invitationInfo object: AnyObject) {
    eventId = object["eventId"] as? String
    message = object["message"] as? String
    location = object["location"] as? String
}
```

In the above area Xcode ask to unwrap all the values.

[image]

I am not able to understand what to do. Cause I can not give guarantee that those values will come as string.

Comment: How are `eventId` etc declared?

Comment: var eventId: String?

Comment: How are you calling the `design` function? What is the `invitationInfo object`?

Comment: I call it as like normal method calling with a `Dictionary `

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing GoogleAnalytics with cocoapods. I don't know where this error come from but you can try this to guarantee object's values are String:

```
func design(invitationInfo object: AnyObject) {
    if object["eventId"] is String {
        eventId = object["eventId"] as! String
    }
    if object["message"] is String {
        message = object["message"] as! String
    }
    if object["location"] is String {
        location = object["location"] as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes we can do. But this is not the optimal solution. I just illustrate the problem by one method. There total 286 error caught.  If I really need to do that you suggested, will be very hectic.

Comment: You right, probably not the right solution for 286 errors... You can try to import Google Analytics like this `#import <Google/Analytics.h>` maybe a piece of code is missing in the way you are importing it. You can also try to clean your project (Shift+cmd+K), it works like magic some times ^^

Answer (score -1):

As error Says You have to use '!' ,

Try Below code,

`let eventID: String? = object["eventID"]`

After creating `eventID` you need to check it for nil before using it.